# Trying to eliminate '1900-01-01' from converted date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I realise that there are other threads covering this but I can't find one that solves my problem.

I have three text columns that either contain a date or nothing (null), I'm converting the text to a date in order to use date filters once the date makes it to Excel.

Obviously, the null values get converted to '1900-01-01' but I can't find a way to show them as blanks, even with a subquery.

This is what I'm doing...

```
Select top 999999999
OtherFields,

case when Engdate = '19000101' then '' else Engdate end as 'EngDate',

OtherOtherFields

from
(

select 
OtherFields,

case 
when VAR_AppID = '3' then nullif( CONVERT(date,concat(right([2201],4), 
SUBSTRING([2201],4,2), left([2201],2))),null)
        else nullif( CONVERT(date,concat(right([3429],4), 
SUBSTRING([3429],4,2), left([3429],2))),null) end as 'Engdate',

case when ([2201] is not null and Len([2201])  = 10 ) then 
CONVERT(date,concat(right([2201],4), SUBSTRING([2201],4,2), left([2201],2)))
else null end as 'EngagementRec',

OtherOtherFields

from

Tables
)
```

The fields [2201], and [3429] are the text fields that contain the dates in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.

Am I supposed to covert back to a text format to allow the '' to show a blank - and if so, will the dates still be recognised as dates?

Comment: [3429] (and [2201]) are column names.

Comment: Ok.. I'm clear now.. can u please give example data

Comment: It's self-explanatory. NULL values for date fields show as '1900-01-01'...I want them to show a blank field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this one myself as I can't find anything that works.
Any combination of case statments, ISNULL(), NULLIF() etc result in either NULL or '1900-01-01'. Converting to text makes the date field unusable in Excel.

As the data will be coming into an Excel pivot table, I don't desperately need to resolve this as pivot tables eliminate null values anyway.

...I might come back to this if I need to show the data in a list.

Thanks to everyone that made suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

As per answer of Anthony Green on [sqlservercentral](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/replace-datetime-column-with-null-as-empty-string), you may try:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, DateTimeColumnName,23),'') as DateTimeColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the ms help on the Concat function (which is sql 2012 onwards not 2008) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> If CONCAT receives arguments with all NULL values, it will return an empty 
>   string of type varchar(1).

A zero length string will be implicitly converted to zero giving you the zero date in sql server. You need to handle the nulls before trying to convert the way you have done it. 
Maybe use Try_convert instead.
Use try_convert with the right option. 
TRY_CONVERT(Datetime, columnwithstringdate, 103)

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks - and I've updated the tag (not sure why I did that!).

Comment: Try_convert is great for dates that you get as strings. It will not crash the whole query if you get a dodgy date string. Not sure excel likes the date data type. I think it prefers the Datetime in general.

Comment: I like the Try_Convert - it's much tidier. I'm still getting '1900-01-01' if I try to eliminate the NULLs though - either with ISNULL or with a CASE statement.

Comment: The try_convert should return null if the string is null. Are the strings definitely null or are they zero length strings? Please can you post some sample data?

Comment: Try_convert should leave nulls as null which should appear as blank in excel but zero length strings will be converted to zero dates. SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '', 103), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, NULL,103)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Converting them text first won't do any bad (I think).
Try the following:

```
Select top 999999999
OtherFields,

case when Engdate = '19000101' then '' else CONVERT(CHAR(10), EngDate, 120) end as 'EngDate' end as 'EngDate',

OtherOtherFields

from
(

select 
OtherFields,

case 
when VAR_AppID = '3' then nullif( CONVERT(date,concat(right([2201],4), 
SUBSTRING([2201],4,2), left([2201],2))),null)
        else nullif( CONVERT(date,concat(right([3429],4), 
SUBSTRING([3429],4,2), left([3429],2))),null) end as 'Engdate',

case when ([2201] is not null and Len([2201])  = 10 ) then 
CONVERT(date,concat(right([2201],4), SUBSTRING([2201],4,2), left([2201],2)))
else null end as 'EngagementRec',

OtherOtherFields

from

Tables
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, converting an empty string to the date datatype returns 1900-01-01.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT CAST ('' as date) AS [thedate]
```

Returns:

```
thedate
1900-01-01
```

The NULL value, when casted to the date datatype is still NULL.
Based on your code, I think all you have to do is change this line:

```
case when Engdate = '19000101' then '' else Engdate end as 'EngDate',
```

to:

```
case when Engdate = '19000101' then NULL else Engdate end as 'EngDate',
```

Comment: ...yes, but that gives me NULL values - what I'm looking for is a bank where the NULLs are. If I use ISNULL, the '1900-01-01' values come back.