# How to convert 1900-01-01 to null in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My SQL query output looks like this.

| ID | UPC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 1900-01-01 |

UPC is a date column.

How do I convert 1900-01-01 to null?

I tried following instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820355/trying-to-eliminate-1900-01-01-from-converted-date-column), but I am getting ***SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 22 invalid identifier 'DATE'***

```
select ISNULL(CONVERT(date, UPC,23),'') as  UPC from TEST23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html):

> Returns NULL if expr1 is equal to expr2, otherwise returns expr1.

```
SELECT ID, NULLIF(UPC, '1900-01-01'::DATE) AS UPC
FROM TEST123
```